# Does the Nano edited file not get updated after reboot?

Tags: scripts, 22.04, hostname, nano

I am using the nano command to update the file and save it, however, the file has not taken effect after the system rebooted. The file was not updated after checking again. Nano editor version 6.0.1, Ubuntu 22.04.
How to fix this problem?

---

I am editing the /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts these two files. My system is Raspberry 3b hardware.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details which file you edited. Please share the filename and the  full path to the file.

Comment: Which file, specifically? Is the file managed by a systemd service? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: try vi or "sudo -E gedit /etc/hosts"

Comment: @petep if `nano` cannot save the file, then neither can `vi` or `gedit`.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually saved the file correctly, then it has been saved and rebooting won't have any effect. Actually, just saving the file after editing it already updates the file. When rebooting, the system will read the updated file.

If it does not work for you, then you are doing something wrong.

1. *Make sure you have the proper permissions*: for editing system files, you need to have superuser privileges.
2. *Make sure you open the correct file*: are you actually opening the file you intend to open?
3. *Make sure there are no messages during saving*: saving  a file in nano should not produce any messages. Messages may be seen, for example, if you try to save the changed file, but do not have the required permissions.
4. After saving, and before rebooting, open the file again and check that your changes are there.